# Jquery getJSON not working with debian apache

Tags: jquery, json

I'm making a very simple ajax call

```
var factString = "",
    jsonFile = "http://localhost/cp11/facts1.json";
$.getJSON( jsonFile, function( data ) {
    factString = data;
}).fail(function(e) { 
    debugger;
});
```

If I call the url in my firefox browser it displays the file just fine.

Also the JQuery command following the getJSON works fine, if I set factString to a JSON string:

```
fact = $.parseJSON( factString );
```

But getJSON never calls the callback function, also not the fail-function.
I'm puzzled.

Comment: first of all; the webserver doesn't matter at all, as the browser doesn't know about it (it only cares about the response, not _who_ is sending the response). Furthermore; please check the console and check if there are any errors, that's the first step in solving your problem :)

Comment: There is nothing in the console. Not in Firefox and not in Chrome.

Comment: If I choose a file name that is not valid, then it goes into the fail function, and in the console is a 404.

Comment: I can't speak for Firefox, but in Chrome (if the console is open when the call is made), you should see the call and an indication of its response.  If you're not seeing that then the call is not being made.